# Typescript RefForwardingComponent not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am trying to make my component accept a ref.

I have a component like so:

```js
const MyComponent: RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> = (props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>Hoopla</div>
}
```

But when I try to pass a ref to is like so:

```js
<MyComponent ref={myRef}></MyComponent>
```

... I get this error:

```
Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IMyComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20):

`RefForwardingComponent` is a [*render function*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components), which receives props and ref parameters and returns a React node - it is *no* component:

> The second ref argument only exists when you define a component with React.forwardRef call. Regular function or class components don’t receive the ref argument, and ref is not available in props either. ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components))

That is also the reason, why `RefForwardingComponent` is [deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45ba9c4ac8524a58e2c8a84eb449d2af339/types/react/index.d.ts#L541-L545) in favor of `ForwardRefRenderFunction`, which is functionally equivalent, but has a different name to make the distinction clearer.

You use [`React.forwardRef`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45ba9c4ac8524a58e2c8a84eb449d2af339/types/react/index.d.ts#L767) to turn the render function into an actual component that accepts refs:

```
import React, { ForwardRefRenderFunction } from 'react'

type IMyComponentProps = { a: string }
const MyComponentRenderFn: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> =
    (props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Hoopla</div>

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef(MyComponentRenderFn);
const myRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

<MyComponent a="foo" ref={myRef} />
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is right but you are missing a small detail.

When you use `RefForwardingComponent` you need to export the component wrapped with `forwardRef`

```
import React, { forwardRef, RefForwardingComponent } from 'react';

type IMyComponentProps = {}
const MyComponent: RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> = (props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>Hoopla</div>
}

export default forwardRef(MyComponent);
```

Comment: OP's issue is a compile-time Type error.  It will not be fixed by `forwardRef`.  A missing `forwardRef` will eventually cause a runtime error: `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`.  So OP does need forwardRef, but he hasn't made it that far yet.

Comment: @Warren , You are right the issue is a compile-time Type error.
The type that is returned by forwardRef function is a type that accepts the ref prop.
`ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>`
This basically wraps your component accepting your props (** PropsWithoutRef**) and the 'ref' prop (**RefAttributes**)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in React's type definitions for `RefForwardingComponent`.  You can work around this by adding the `ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>` to your props.  This will fix your compiler error.

try this:

```js
type IMyComponentProps = {
    ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
}
```

I believe this requirement is a bug, because it should be added to the props for you by `RefForwardingComponent`.  Putting it in your own props means that TypeScript will expect the `props` argument inside your function to contain the `ref` prop and I don't think it does.  This however is not a big problem.

Answer (score -1):

Custom function components can't have 'ref' as a prop. You will have to give it a different name. 'yourRef', for example will be inside the props object.

```
<MyComponent yourRef={myRef}></MyComponent>
```

So to use the ref prop:

```
const MyComponent: RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> = (props) => {
return <div ref={props.yourRef}>Hoopla</div>}
```

or you can descructure the props:

```
const MyComponent: RefForwardingComponent<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> = ({yourRef}) => {
return <div ref={yourRef}>Hoopla</div>}
```

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but I thought that `RefForwardingComponent` is suppose to make your custom components accept a ref?