# React.ForwardRef TypeScript Component Type Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Block` component which will render a `div` or `a` tag based on a prop value. I want to pass a ref from the parent component to this component. Therefore, I need to use `RefForwardingComponent` type for my component variable type, but I get an error for type incompatibility between `HTMLAnchorElement` and `HTMLDivElement`. How can I fix it? [here's the component code on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-wildflower-lzhu7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FBlock.tsx&theme=dark):

```ts
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  isLink: boolean;
}

type PropsWithElementProps<T> = React.HTMLProps<T> & Props;

type RefComponent<T, U> =
  | React.RefForwardingComponent<T, PropsWithElementProps<T>>
  | React.RefForwardingComponent<U, PropsWithElementProps<U>>;

// error for Block variable type... full error on CodeSandBox link
const Block: RefComponent<HTMLAnchorElement, HTMLDivElement> = React.forwardRef(
  ({ isLink }, ref) => {
    if (isLink)
      return (
        <a ref={ref} href="#nothing">
          I'm a link!
        </a>
      );
    else return <div ref={ref}>I'm a div!</div>;
  }
);

export default Block;
```

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991706/typescript-refforwardingcomponent-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`React.forwardedRef` expects you to provide a type for the returned element and the props in cases where it cannot be inferred. You can indicate it like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  isLink?: boolean;
}

const Block = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement & HTMLDivElement, Props>(
  ({ isLink = false }, ref) => {
    return isLink ? (
      <a ref={ref} href="#nothing">
        {"I'm a link!"}
      </a>
    ) : (
      <div ref={ref}>{"I'm a div!"}</div>
    );
  }
);

export default Block;
```

The `forwardRef` type definition looks like this:

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is working. Can you explain this a little bit more, please? why would I combine the types of HTMLAnchorELEment and HTMLDivElement when my component only returns one of them? why it shouldn't be HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLDivElement?