# Using TypeScript with React HOC, React.lazy and forwarRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to write an HOC that wrap a component by using `React.lazy` and `React.Suspense` in TypeScript, but I don't know how to fix the types errors.

```js
type AsyncComponentFactory<P> = () => Promise<{ default: ComponentType<P> }>;

export function loadable<P>(factory: AsyncComponentFactory<P>): ComponentType<P> {
  const LazyComponent = React.lazy(factory);

  const WrappedWithLoadableComponent = forwardRef<P>((props: P, ref) => (
    <React.Suspense fallback={'loading'}>
      <LazyComponent {...props} ref={ref} />
    </React.Suspense>
  ));

  WrappedWithLoadableComponent.displayName = 'LazyExoticComponent(loadableComponent)';

  return WrappedWithLoadableComponent;
}

const JobsView = loadable(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "JobsView" */ '@views/Jobs'));
```

[image: Error]

Comment: some times @ts-ignore is best practice

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think this is due to limitation of react.
See the type of `forwardRef`:

```js
    function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

React expects `PropsWithoutRef` and you are trying to use ref. I think it is wrong.
You should use this example:

```js
import React, { ForwardRefRenderFunction } from 'react'

type IMyComponentProps = { a: string }
const MyComponentRenderFn: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLDivElement, IMyComponentProps> =
    (props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Hoopla</div>

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef(MyComponentRenderFn);
const myRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

<MyComponent a="foo" ref={myRef} />
```

All credits goes to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991706/typescript-refforwardingcomponent-not-working)